# Ruby on Rails - login with cookie or username / password - always hitting the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

UPDATE:  All, thanks for the responses - here is some more significant info.

I'm using a Neo4J graph database for the back-end, ROR 3 (MRI), and one single Neo4J database server accessed via REST.

If you don't know much about Neo4j, to use more than one database server (master/master) for data costs $26,000, which means I have to code for optimization now, not later, or come up with $26k...I'm sure you can guess which way I'm going with this..And I'm using it via rest, not locally etc, so performance matters...

I have **one** database server that has to handle all of the database work, and yes 1 ms counts under this scenario where some other queries take up to 40 ms.  So no, I don't want to hit the database unnecessarily as it will simply add unnecessary work to it.

It might be easy to say "don't code for optimizations or problems you don't have yet" yet given the bottleneck and steep costs - and the fact I already have what I need done except for the authentication piece, it really doesn't apply.

What I simply wanted to know, was if the @current_user ||= is valid across pages.. The answer is that it's valid in a request, and not across them or pages.  Yes this is a simple question, but sometimes they have to be asked in the midst of R&D and advanced stuff. Hence my gut feeling to stick with sessions to hold the id of the user logged in.

Thanks for your help!

---

I'm trying to allow a user to login to my site either by cookies or by username and password. The username/password part works fine, but having a problem with introducing cookies....

I've ready plenty of "how tos" including:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out

I do not want to use a gem, devise, etc.

PROBLEM:

I notice that requests from the page to read current_user (a helper in the application controller) results in database reads, even though I'm using ||=..

I've tried the @current_user ||= User.find by blah blah blah

and it ALWAYS hits the database.  This shoudn't be the case right? It should hit once and then that's it, correct?

But before you suggest any tutorial - I've seen tons of them - here is my question.. is @current_user saved across pages, or just for the current page?  The link above mentions it only saves it for the current page...

You see, I don't want to keep hitting the database needlessly to find out the same person previously is logged in.. I can do that with session variables.

I really just want to check for a cookie,and would be happy to keep on using session[:user_id] after that.. for performance reasons, I do not want to keep hitting the database.

Any help?

My NEW code is below (and this too always hits the database as it should in this instance).  I removed the typical @current_user ||= find_by.. because it was useless - it was *always* hitting the db.

.. I already tried https://github.com/cliftonm/basic-auth and http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out etc..

(ROR 3.2...)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  #before_filter :set_var

  helper_method :current_user

private



def current_user

         @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) #if session[:user_id]
         if (@current_user)
           return @current_user
         end


       @current_user =User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
       if (@current_user)
         return @current_user
       end


 end
```

Comment: back to basics: for every request the server must redo everything

Comment: Hey!!  That's what I was looking for! I have the advanced stuff, but was asking a basic question.. So, basically, I'd be better off relying on session variables? That would mean allowing the cookie to log in, but then using session variables from then on out, right? Which makes all of these examples useless to me.. I do not want the overhead of hitting the DB every time, which almost every example out there does..

Comment: In general retrieving the user should not be heavy on the DB. As the previous poster said, HTTP is stateless and so should your controller.  You can choose to store more in the session to avoid loading the user as much but if you index the user_id the overhead is not that substantial so I would not worry about the DB hit.

Answer (score 4):

`User.find` will always hit the database unless you have some kind of cache extension loaded. `Rails.cache` can be configured several ways, but the most popular, if this sort of thing is required, is [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Unless you're dealing with massive scaling issues, the time required to fetch a user record should be less than 1ms, so it's hardly worth fussing about. Check your `log/development.log` to see the execution times of your various queries and focus first on the slowest ones.

Instance variables like `@current_user` persist *only* for the duration of the request. Remember that the HTTP protocol is stateless, each request exists independent of the others, and the only way to communicate state is via cookies, a persistent store like a database, a temporary store like an in-memory cache, or by parameters sent in with the request itself via GET or POST.

If you want to save something across pages, add it to the `session`, but be careful. You should only be persisting things like strings, numbers, or booleans. You should not be adding models. Further, using the default cookie store, each thing you put in the session increases the overhead on *all* requests made to your application from that point forward until you remove that from your `session` store.

Don't sweat the little things until you've got all the other problems solved. Business logic first, optimization second.

Comment: +1 people always tend to worry about scaling and premature optimization when most of them will never hit that scale.  You can always optimize later in situations like this.

Comment: I have literally dozens of apps in production use where `User.find` is absolutely last on my list of things to optimize. You can spend hours fiddling with this to shave off a fraction of a millisecond when your users are wondering why your page is so slow because of how huge your CSS file is, or why you're loading a half dozen heavy JavaScript libraries on every page.

Comment: I understand user.find will always it the db.. What I'm getting at is unnecessarily hitting the database (see my edit to the original question).  But thanks for the answer re instance variables.

Comment: I won't worry about the database overhead. I bet you'd have a hard time even measuring it. You should be concerned about database calls that routinely take measurable time, or are inside of a loop. Always watch `log/development.log` to see what each page rendering call is doing in the background because it can be surprising what's going on.

Comment: Depending entirely on data in `session` is problematic. What if the user has been deleted? Banned? Suspended? What if you've reset the user database and that old `user_id` now refers to a new user? Don't think accessing the database is needless. Is it causing performance problems for you? Why are you so concerned about a single call?

Comment: If you're worried about overloading your Neo4J database, I wouldn't use that for storing user data. Pick a traditional RDBMS for those tables, like Postgres or even MySQL, something with more reasonable license fees. I have doubts that a single query is going to cost you another server license. If so, you need to work on tuning this database better. I can't emphasize enough here that you seem to be fretting about something that *should* be inconsequential.

Comment: Have you explored [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) like I suggested? That can serve as a way of reducing database calls, but invalidating caches can be tricky. I would start out doing this the traditional way, benchmark it aggressively with a realistic or even pessimistically complicated data set, and tackle the low-hanging fruit first. I have never seen something like `User.find` be #1 on that list.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these should be slamming the database every time. Please let me know.

```
     if (@current_user)
       @current_user
     else
       @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
     end
```

or

```
     @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a before_filter (instead of a helper) to load current_user only once? You would then store it / access it using an instance variable.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :load_current_user

  def load_current_user
    @current_user = # your code goes here.
  end
end
```

Edit:

My bad. How about storing a server-side encrypted current_user record in the cookie, and keeping the hashsum in the session for later checkup?

Comment: This is wrong, it will not persist between requests.  before_filter just stops code duplication, does not change the fact that it is called every request.

Comment: While not a bad idea in general, the question was related to something other than this.